# Javascript MouseMove Event Coding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, onmousemove

I am trying to do an assignment for class and basically it has to be "interactive". I want to use the mousemove syntax to change the color and size of the lines that I made. I made my lines in a div in my html file and did the `getElementById` syntax to make the lines.

I have the lines...I don't know how to make them move and change color. My professor sent me code and he made the lines change color as the mouse moved over them. I understand the code but I don't know how to make the lines move and change size randomly when the mouse is moved over them.

Do I need to create individual div's for each line to make them move, change color randomly, and change size randomly independently of one another or can I just do what I did, make one div with multiple lines and make them do what I want, independently of each other?

Here is a link to my code below!

Thank you!!!!!

```
    [1]: http://codepen.io/niymil/pen/pNoOqz



     var w = 100;
var h = 500;

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

function adjustLineStyle(y, lineY) {
  var distance = Math.abs(lineY - y);
  var lightness = 100 - distance;
  // hsl makes a color HUE, SATURATION, LIGHTNESS.
  // lightness will be how far Y is from the Y of line.
  ctx.strokeStyle = "hsl(80, 70%," + lightness + "%)";
  ctx.lineWidth = 2;
};

function clear() {
  ctx.fillStyle = 'hsla(0,0%,0%,0.1)';
  ctx.fillRect(0,0,500,500);
}

var startX = 0 ;
var endX = 500 ;

function drawlines(mouseEvent) {
  var mouseY = mouseEvent.offsetY;
  startX = startX + (Math.random() -0.5) * 30;
  endX = endX + (Math.random()  - 0.5) * 30;
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'white'
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(startX, mouseY);
  ctx.lineTo(endX, mouseY);
  ctx.stroke();
}

setInterval(clear,50);
document.addEventListener('mousemove', drawlines);
//draw lines as as the mouse is hovered over the lines
//the lines are supposed to change size as the mouse is hovered over the canvas
//as lines reappear, they should change color randomly
```

Comment: Can you copy/paste your code into the actual question please? You can do this by clicking on the little  `< > `  icon when you click on `edit` at the bottom of your question

Comment: I dont see any lines at all... am I missing something here?

Comment: Good job.. You're almost there.. Just missing one little thing..

try adding   `$(document).ready(function(){ animateDiv();   });`   in there somewhere and you got it

Answer (score 0):

here is a good place to start looking for answers

https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Also try hitting the `Run` button at the end of the answer if you're still stuck

```js
var w = 100;
var h = 500;


var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");


   
document.ready(function(){
    animateDiv();  
});



function makeNewPosition() {
  var h = $(window).height() - 50;
  var w = $(window).width() - 50;
  var nh = Math.floor(Math.random() * h);
  var nw = Math.floor(Math.random() * w);
  return [nh, nw];
}

function animateDiv() {
  var newq = makeNewPosition();
  var oldq = $('canvas').offset();
  var speed = calcSpeed([oldq.top, oldq.left], newq);
  $('canvas').animate({
    top: newq[0],
    left: newq[1]
  }, speed, function() {
    animateDiv();
  });
};

function calcSpeed(prev, next) {
  var x = Math.abs(prev[1] - next[1]);
  var y = Math.abs(prev[0] - next[0]);
  var greatest = x > y ? x : y;
  var speedModifier = 0.1;
  var speed = Math.ceil(greatest / speedModifier);
  return speed;
}

function adjustLineStyle(y, lineY) {
  var distance = Math.min(Math.abs(lineY - y), 1000);
  var lightness = 100 - distance;
  var maxSize = 5;
  ctx.strokeStyle = "hsl(80, 70%," + lightness + "%)";
  ctx.lineWidth = maxSize * (lightness / 100);
};

function drawlines(mouseEvent) {
  var mouseY = mouseEvent.offsetY;
  for (var x = 0; x < 1000; x += 15) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    adjustLineStyle(x, mouseY);
    ctx.moveTo(500, x);
    ctx.lineTo(x, x);
    ctx.stroke();
  }
}

document.addEventListener('mousemove', drawlines);
//redraw lines as as the mouse is hovered over the existing lines
//the lines are supposed to change size as the mouse is hovered over the canvas
//as lines reappear, they should change color randomly
```

```css
.name {
  font-family: Poiret One;
  color: #BC8F8F;
  font-size: 25px;
  line-height: 4px;
  border-bottom: dotted 2px;
  width: 7em;
}
body {
  background: #696969;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poiret+One" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" />

<body>

  <div class=name>
    <p>Niyah Gonzalez</p>
    <p>2016/1/11</p>
    <p>PS-07</p>
  </div>


  <div class="canvas">
    <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
    </br>
  </div>



  <script type="text/javascript" src="square.js"></script>

  </script>

</body>

</html>
```